# How can I remove the border around all the cells in a table?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a table structured like the one below and it is a on page with a gray background. The problem I am having is removing the cell borders.

```
<table width="510">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #fff;" colspan="2" width="510"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #fff;"></td>
<tdstyle="background-color: #fff;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #fff;"></td>
<td style="background-color: #fff;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is what it looks like no matter what I have tried such as adding a .no-border class `border:0;` to the `<tr>` or adding inline css to the `<td>`. It still comes out like this...

[image]

How can I remove the border around all the cells?

Comment: FYI, you have a mistake in the 2nd row, 2nd column. There should be a space between `td` and `style`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the cellspacing like this:

```
table { 
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

This is equivalent for the `cellspacing="0"` HTML attribute. See this example:

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table width="510">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #fff;" colspan="2" width="510">t</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #fff;">t</td>
      <td style="background-color: #fff;">t</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #fff;">t</td>
      <td style="background-color: #fff;">t</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">t</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: To clarify, the "border" you see in the screenshot is no border, but the gray body background shining through.